# How do I install the latest empathy 3.11+ in Ubuntu

Tags: dependencies, empathy

I was wondering if someone could give me brief answer regarding if this is possible or not.

I have tried to follow these [instructions](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Empathy/Install)

I downloaded the latest source file, but I seem to have unmet dependencies :

```
E: Unable to locate package telepathy-butterfly
E: Unable to locate package libtelepathy-farsight0
E: Unable to locate package python-tpfarsight
```

Can anyone help?

Best regards

Comment: Any reason you don't want to install 3.8.4?  Which Ubuntu release are you running?

Answer (score 0):

It always depends on your running system. A nice way to check what version is available for your Ubuntu version is to simply check the repository through web:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/

there you can first search for packages and later install them through command line. Helped me alot.